# Strange margin in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, margin

Here is the code:

```
<html><head>
<style>
    *
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px none;
    }
    #left
    {
        float: left;
        height: 90%;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: solid 1px Black;
    }
    #right
    {
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: solid 1px Black;
    }
</style></head><body><div id="left">
    asdasd<br />
    asdasd<br />
    asdasd<br />
</div>
<div id="right">
    asdasd<br />
    asdasd<br />
    asdasd<br />
</div>
```

These 2 div in IE6 are separated by white column. In FireFox it's ok (divs aren't separated). Can you please give me some advice to fix this in IE6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a known IE6 bug. It's best to read here: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/threepxtest.html

A quick fix would be to float to the left both your divs (but it's not always applicable).

Comment: Thank you a lot. Applying "float:left" to both divs really helps.

Comment: However, I'v read about this "3px ie bug" and solved the problem by applying "//margin-right: -3px;" to the left div. It works good.

Comment: Well by using float you don't solve the bug, you just disable the reproduction conditions. The fix is indeed applying a negative 3px margin.